# gradient effects used in this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

[image]

Hi all,

Love how this look, and was wondering what sort of gradient effects may've been used in the image...

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Hi,  i'm wondering specifically in the background, what sort of effects might have been used. Definitely doesn't seem it's a solid color... I tried linear gradient, but didn't do the trick.....

Comment: Just appears to be a [reflected gradient with objects having soft drop shadows.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oRkuC.png)

Comment: I think you'd gain more if you try to replicate it.